# Running a bash script from Putty on a remote server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash, putty

I was advised to post here after my question was closed on Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to run a bash script on a remote server using Putty over SSH. I'm on a Windows 10 machine and the script is saved on the server. It's an interactive script so I need to be able to enter some data after the script is run.

This is what I've tried so far:

1) Log in via Putty

2) Navigate to the directory where the script is saved

3) Enter the command

`sh scriptname.sh`

At this point Putty returns the message:

`forbidden command: sh`

What am I getting wrong? Is Putty the wrong tool for what I'm trying to do?

I've already talked to the admin about it and he claims to be able to run the script from a normal user account, but he wasn't of any help otherwise.

Comment: Try adding executable permission to the script: `chmod +x scriptname.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not putty giving that error - it is the remote server that is giving that error.

All of the text you see inside the putty window after you've logged in, is coming from the other side.

You'll need to check what you are allowed to do/run on that remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output `forbidden command: sh` your ssh account are set to [lshell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell) as a shell. Basically it's purpose to limit commands to a very small set. So you can't run your script from it. Even if you do, most likely it will fail because command set are very restricted.

There is no regular way to run scripts from `lshell`. You can try asking your admin to change your account shell to `bash` if it is possible to run custom scripts.